# Getting the Percentage of changes

Tags: php, arrays, object

How can i get the percentage of the changes which happened?

Like

```
 1. date    1343360810     objectId 1628
    field 10 value 3
 1. date    1242360811     objectId 1628
    field 10 value 5
 1. date    1243364812     objectId 1628
    field 10 value 5
 1. date    1240360814     objectId 1628
    field 10 value 5
```

This would mean the value has ben changed 1 time in 4 objects. 
This would result a percentage of 25% .

My question is how can i do that in PHP.

I have Objects like this an.

```
  [69]=>
  object(stdClass)#92 (6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(7) "1824709"
    ["objectId"]=>
    string(4) "1628"
    ["type"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["field"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "1243360814"
  }

[70]=>
  object(stdClass)#93 (6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(7) "1826225"
    ["objectId"]=>
    string(4) "1628"
    ["type"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["field"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "1243360814"
  }
```

Comment: Can you please format the question a bit? Do you need to do this with PHP or are you fetching the information from database?

Comment: I fetch it from DB. Yes i need to do this in PHP

Comment: Loop through your data count whenever the last values is not equal to the current value. After that you got it:  changes / count * 100.

Comment: hmm.. sounds good but where to get the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate the array of objects and keep track when the value changes. Something like this should do:

```
$oldvalue = false; // This is to exclude the first value from registering as a change
$changes = 0;
foreach($object_array as $obj) {
  if($oldvalue !== false && $obj->value != $oldvalue)
    $changes++;
  $oldvalue = $obj->value;
}
$change_percentage = $changes / count($object_array) * 100;
```

Comment: where do you get $change_percentage = $changes / count($objects) * 100;

$objects ? or is it $object_array or $obj ?

Comment: where do you get objects from?

Comment: In this example $object_array was originally named $objects, I renamed it for clarity but forgot to change the last row. Fixed, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: ...and $object_array refers to the array which holds your data. If it's not in array form (MySQL resource, for instance) you'll need to replace the foreach() with whatever you use to iterate through the data.